# Javascript banner slides overlaying eachother on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, banner

I am having a issue with my JavaScript banner. I only want to make the first slide appear on the page load. Currently the banner jumps to the last slide for a split second then jumps back to first slide. Here is my JavaScript. I am new at this, I have been searching all over the internet with no luck and would appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
var jqb_vCurrent = 0;
var jqb_vTotal = 0;
var jqb_vDuration = 6000;
var jqb_intInterval = 0;
var jqb_vGo = 1;
var jqb_vIsPause = false;
var jqb_tmp = 20;
var jqb_title;
var jqb_imgW = 680;
var jqb_imgH = 200;

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jqb_vTotal = $(".jqb_slides").children().size() -1;
$(".jqb_info").text($(".jqb_slide").attr("title")); 
jqb_intInterval = setInterval(jqb_fnLoop, jqb_vDuration);

//Horizontal
$("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide").each(function(i) { 
    jqb_tmp = ((i - 1)*jqb_imgW) - ((jqb_vCurrent -1)*jqb_imgW);
    $(this).animate({"left": jqb_tmp+"px"}, 500);
});


$("#btn_pauseplay").click(function() {
    if(jqb_vIsPause){
        jqb_fnChange();
        jqb_vIsPause = false;
        $("#btn_pauseplay").removeClass("jqb_btn_play");
        $("#btn_pauseplay").addClass("jqb_btn_pause");
    } else {
        clearInterval(jqb_intInterval);
        jqb_vIsPause = true;
        $("#btn_pauseplay").removeClass("jqb_btn_pause");
        $("#btn_pauseplay").addClass("jqb_btn_play");
    }
});
$("#btn_prev").click(function() {
    jqb_vGo = -1;
    jqb_fnChange();
});

$("#btn_next").click(function() {
    jqb_vGo = 1;
    jqb_fnChange();
});
});

function jqb_fnChange(){
clearInterval(jqb_intInterval);
jqb_intInterval = setInterval(jqb_fnLoop, jqb_vDuration);
jqb_fnLoop();
}

function jqb_fnLoop(){
if(jqb_vGo == 1){
    jqb_vCurrent == jqb_vTotal ? jqb_vCurrent = 0 : jqb_vCurrent++;
} else {
    jqb_vCurrent == 0 ? jqb_vCurrent = jqb_vTotal : jqb_vCurrent--;
}


$("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide").each(function(i) { 
    if(i == jqb_vCurrent){
        jqb_title = $(this).attr("title");
        $(".jqb_info").animate({ opacity: 'hide', "left": "-50px"}, 250,function(){
            $(".jqb_info").text(jqb_title).animate({ opacity: 'show', "left": "0px"}, 500);
        });
    } 


    //Horizontal Scrolling
    jqb_tmp = ((i - 1)*jqb_imgW) - ((jqb_vCurrent -1)*jqb_imgW);
    $(this).animate({"left": jqb_tmp+"px"}, 500);


});


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't animate every `#jqb_object.jqb_slide` element on `document.ready` ?

**Edit**

Instead of

```
//Horizontal
$("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide").each(function(i) { 
    jqb_tmp = ((i - 1)*jqb_imgW) - ((jqb_vCurrent -1)*jqb_imgW);
    $(this).animate({"left": jqb_tmp+"px"}, 500);
});
```

try

```
//Horizontal
i = 1;
jqb_tmp = ((i - 1)*jqb_imgW) - ((jqb_vCurrent -1)*jqb_imgW);
$("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide:first").animate({"left": jqb_tmp+"px"}, 500);
```

if you want your last slide to appear on page load with its own caption, change `jqb_vCurrent` index:

```
jqb_vCurrent = jqb_vTotal;
```

Comment: I tried, but I cannot get it to work. I am so stuck on this. Since I posted this I added some other code to stop the animation buildup issue I was having. So where you told me to place the code

Comment: sorry, got cut off. So that snippet oc de looks like this now:

Comment: Thanks a bunch for getting back to me. So I put in the code you suggested, and I still cannot get it to work. I get a syntax error. Am I doing something wrong?Code makes me sooo crazy! $("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide:first").animate({"left": jqb_tmp+"px"}, 500); { 
  jqb_tmp = ((i - 1)*jqb_imgW) - ((jqb_vCurrent -1)*jqb_imgW);
  $(this).stop().animate({"left": jqb_tmp+"px"}, 500); 
 });

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure about this solution, but check my edited answer

Comment: @h4bo I am almost there. Thanks so much. Now the last slide appears by itself on the pageload, but I can work around that. I do have another small issue going on. On each slide I have the title tag in the div of each slide, which appears as a caption on the bottom of each corresponding slide. Now on page load the last slide appears first with the first slides caption. I can post the html code if that would help. Thanks again. You are a life saver.

Comment: I am also getting an error on my Webpage javascipt
'i' is undefined

Comment: I thought my latest edit should help you - but again, I'm not an expoert on this subject.